# Смогу ли я сделать распознавание номеров на Raspberry PI первой модели и OpenCV?

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi

Решил попробовать реализовать компьютерное зрение на Raspberry PI первой модели, но не знаю, хватит ли мне железа для получения желаемого результата. Подскажите, на что хватит железки? Смогу ли я сделать распознавание номеров, например или упрусь в какой-то примитивный функционал?

Comment: Железо скорее всего позволит, правда FullHD ганять не выйдет скорее всего (выйдет, но будет очень долго и медленно).
А вот получится ли у Вас - это зависит только от Вас, а не от железа.

Comment: Я хочу понять, сможет железка детектить раз в минуту предмет из видео потока, или же сможет с камерой на больших скоростях гоняться за кошкой :) Нужно понять предел.

Comment: само устройство сможет отдать Вам 3-4 кадра в секунду размером 640х480. А вот сможете ли Вы их правильно обработать... Для погони за кошкой этого маловато. А вот за ленивцами - самое оно.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо. думаю, маловато для моих задач.

Comment: в любом случае, я бы рекомендовал попробовать. малинки есть разные, плюс, я тестил в свое время на юсб камере, возможно, интегрированная даст больше. Но, возможно, Вам нужен такой девайс http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5pgyh.html

Comment: Я хотел сделать быструю туррель, которая будет стрелять в страйкболистов вражеской команды. Пока не решил с помощью чего буду отличать команды, но с разрешением 640х480 вряд ли удастся подстрелить быстро бегущего вдалеке человека. да, можно делать поправку на опережение, но в этом случае выстрел будет произведен в конце видимой траектории движения. Хочется иметь больший запас времени для подсчетов и корректировок. У меня есть мини пк, который, скорее всего, придется использовать. бюджет маленький на эту задачу, придется использовать то, что есть.

Comment: поправку Вам в любом случае придется делать. И так как человек обычно не изменяет свою траекторию "многвенно", то все можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RasPI содержит прекрасный интерфейс MIPI CSI для камеры, штатные камеры (приобретаются отдельно) позволяют получать видеопоток FullHD/30, HD/60 VGA/90. 
А вот процессора RasPI может не хватить. FullHD он точно не потянет, и вам точно FullHD не нужен.

- берите дополнительный длиннофокусный объектив для RasPI camera (на
  амазоне их куча), настройте фокус на определенную дальность - где
  номера проезжающих машин лучше всего видны
- снимайте видеопоток VGA
- для распознавания можно использовать [OpenALPR](http://www.openalpr.com/), на RasPI будет
  конечно подтормаживать поскольку использует Tesseract. Но говорят
  терпимо.

Можно взять [платку получше](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers) чем малина - но обязательно с MIPI CSI и чтобы камеры под плату были готовые к подключению.

Хорошее видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBAOdj8HABc  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcMPemzifbQ